# How to make inner div width exactly 4 pixel less the outter div width?

Tags: css, html

The code is like this. I have an outer div, let's say it is 200px wide. I want the inner div to be exactly 4 pixels less than the outer div even if you resize the outer div. I am more concerned about the height though not the width.

I am basically using border with the outer and the inner width so if my inner div is the same width as the outer with, the inner div comes out of the outer div (it is shifted 1px right).

I am essentially looking for something like:

`child.width = parent.width - 4px;`

Answer (score 1):

Could you not simply give the inner div a margin of 2px...?

**AMEND**

bit more complicated than that in reality, but this seems to wrk (forked from Ash's fiddle)...

http://jsfiddle.net/biznuge/FGQRm/11/

Comment: Yeah, and give make the height and width 100% relative to the outer div.

Comment: plz see my comment below. This is a nice idea but does not work for height (works for width). Plus I want the two borders attached so applying padding to the outer div is more desirable for me.

Comment: Thanks it did work. In the actual browser I had to add padding like this : inner-div.padding : 0 4px 4px 0; In jsfiddle, your code worked perfect. Dont know what was wrong in the actual browser. Thanks!

Comment: Good stuff Dave! Guess there might be other factors affecting different pads and margins in your actual project inherited from other styles.

Comment: I was just using a test page, no big project or big CSS cascading. Will check it out again.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use margins for this. Have a look at this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ashburlaczenko/YUcHS/1/

Comment: Type this code in jsfiddle. It almost does what I am intending but height wise the inner div comes out of the outer div.[code] #div1
{
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
#div2
{
    height:100%;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/biznuge/FGQRm/11/ - Your previous post but with an added 4px padding to the bottom of the outer div. OR **inner border width * 2**

Answer (score 0):

Here, this uses basic padding and flexbox

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    .box{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: red;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 4px;
    }
    .mini-box{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: rgb(128, 93, 93);
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="mini-box">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```